# How to listen socket.io client.send event on postman

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am sending message from server by the client.send method and in postman i want to get all messages without adding any event listener like web socket.
In web socket, we do not need to add any event listener,
Similarly, In the socket.io, I want to get all messages without listening to message event like web socket.

server

```
const socketClients = await this.io.fetchSockets();             
socketClients.forEach((client: any) => {
  client.send(JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

This code sends message to the client, when I am adding an event listener to the postman, getting all messages but I want to get messages without adding event listener like web socket.

I hope you understand my question,
hoping a good answer by you,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postman v10.17.1 the feature works good!

1. Check you are in version 10.17.1 or above
2. Make sure the socket.io service is up and running
3. In Postman the most important thing is to check that the version is corralate to the server, for example: if the server is version 2 you need to set v2 on postman setting request:
   [image]
4. In the Events tab of the request, add the event name you want to register to. Make sure the listen in active.
   [image]
5. In the Message tab you put the "emit" function parameters, The emit function struct is : **server.emit(eventName[, ...args])**
   therefor you put in the arguments field the args (usually data for filter), and in the message on the right bottom side the event name.

   **if there is no documantation for event name use the default ("message") and leave it blank.**
   [image]
6. Now click on "connect" and you should get the response down:
   [image]